# Anchor tag href to another page's DIV is not landing on intended/targeted DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making an epub magazine webapp. In that I have navbar.xhtml which list down all my related topic inside the magazine. All the

tags have been given a href to another xhtml file which contains the text/content for that chapter in the magazine.

**navbar.xhtml**

```
<li><a href="chapter001.xhtml#div1"> XYZ </a></li>
```

**chapter001.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <title>ABCDEFGH</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" class="section level1">   
 /*Some huge amount of content goes here */
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But in my case I am being redirected to correct page though but content start from some another element.

Temporary solution applied: I just removed the # from the anchor tag's href attribute. But I don't want this because in near future I may need to link them to sub-chapter in same chapter001.xhtml.

Comment: Link doesn't have quotes

Comment: @zer00ne  I was typing and forgot put the quotes. Sorry ! But yaa my codebase do have quotes in them

Comment: I figured that's it's a simple typo, just more like a FYI. Anyways I noticed the retro old school HTML4 you are rocking here and then I remembered that HTML4 targets the name attribute and HTML5 targets the id attribute.

Comment: Disregard the name/id theory previously commented, I have the solution please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not totally sure about HTML4 and XHTML, but one thing I do know is that XHTML is very strict, like you cannot deviate from it's syntax. It's not flexible with forgiveness as HTML5.
The first line:

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

...is XML I think, so I got rid of that.

The second coincides with XHTML strict, but I had to change `chapter001` extension to `.html` from `.xhtml` to get it working. I'm not sure it was because a server MIME thing or whatever.

The third line didn't look like it belonged there, but I got it to work correctly so that's your call:

> `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

The Plunker consists of 2 web pages: `index.html` and `chapter001.html` They are identical with the exception for their headings which basically used to tell them apart. The links are at the bottom of each page. They are made the same way as are the target `div1`s.

[<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/WVUhkqKbFUESKEDb2c2p/)